# Show div if checkbox is checked onload

Tags: php

I did a bunch of research but seems not to find the correct answer. I am looking to show a div on page load if checkbox is checked where it gets a value from MySQL.

This is my code.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="setup" value="Setup" 
{if $single_array[i].SERVICE == 'Setup'} checked{/if}>
&nbsp;&nbsp;<b>Setup</b>
```

Comment: `... value="Setup" <?php if ($single_array[$i]['SERVICE'] === 'Setup') { echo 'checked="checked"'; } ?>... />`

Comment: Your code is a kind of smarty (template engine based) approach, isn't it?

Comment: yea I am coding in smarty template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey I endup using smarty statements to get this working which also works better

```
{if $test[I].column_name == '1'}
<!--Show Info-->
<p> Test Data</p>

{elseif $test[I].column_name == '2'}
<!--Show Info-->
<p> Test Data</p>

{elseif $test[I].column_name == '3'}
<!--Show Info-->
<p> Test Data</p>
{/if}
```

Thanks all..

Answer (score 1):

So the best way to read a checkbox would be in_array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="red" />
<input type="checkbox" name="color[]" value="yellow" />
```

And the PHP will be-

```
if(in_array("red",$_POST[color])){
  echo "red was checked!";
}else if(in_array("yellow",$_POST[color])){
  echo "yellow was checked!";
}else{
  echo "Nothing checked!";
}
```

You can do the same thing for one or more checkbox as well..

Comment: I was really hoping to use JQuery to have the toggle features as well. I tried this but no luck. http://jsfiddle.net/naPLM/  any recommendations?

Comment: According to your demand, I think it is working. Whats the problem..?

Answer (score 0):

you need to be in PHP to and echo the checked value to the page

```
<input type="checkbox" name="setup" value="Setup" <?php if( $single_array[i].SERVICE == 'Setup'){ echo "checked"; } ?> />
```